# Create and Update a List Item with Javascript in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Hello i'm an beginner and i  try to create/update a SP List with Javascript with an condition.
if a list entry with current users email exist then i will only update the field location
otherwise i will add a new entry. could you please help me

```
    function createUpdateListItem() {
        var siteUrl = 'https://........';
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
        var currentuserID = currentUser.get_email();
        var e = document.getElementById("choice");
        var stdort = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var user = oList.get_item('Email');

        if (user === currentuserID) {
            var listItem = list.getItem('Email');
            listItem.set_item('Location', stdort);
            listItem.update();
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
            this.onQuerySucceededUpdate), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedUpdate)
            );
        }
        function onQuerySucceededUpdate() { alert('Item updated successfully !');
        }

        function onQueryFailedUpdate(sender, args) { alert('Could not able to update item: ' + args.get_message());
        }
        }

        if user != currentuserID {
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            
        oListItem.set_item('Employee', currentUser.get_title());
        oListItem.set_item('Email', currentUser.get_email());
        oListItem.set_item('Location', stdort);
        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededCreate), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedCreate)
        );
      }
    function onQuerySucceededCreate() { alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }
    function onQueryFailedCreate(sender, args) { alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

if i create separate functions as example only create then it works, but i need create or update a list entrie

Comment: Can you provide a list with examples?

Comment: at moment i have a simple sp list with fields Emloyee, Email , Location

Comment: Employee Email Location
Max Mustermann Max.Mustermann@email.com Bonn
Name Nachname Name.Nachname@email.com Köln

Answer (score 0):

First, please check that the {} in your code is correctly paired, such as "if user != currentuserID" is not in the function , then, please write the condition of the if statement in ().

Here is an example of creating and updating a list that you can refer to:

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Name');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);   
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var listItemInfo="";
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var olistitem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo +=olistitem.get_item('Title');
        if(listItemInfo =="fff"){
            this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(olistitem.get_id());
            oListItem.set_item('Title', 'ccc');
                oListItem.update();
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccessUpdate, onQueryFailed);
        }
        else if(listItemInfo !="fff")   {
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem.set_item('Title', 'fff');
                oListItem.update();
                clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccessCreate, onQueryFailed);
        }
        break;
    }
}) 
); } function onsuccessCreate() {alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());} function onsuccessUpdate() {alert('Item updated!');} function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you so so so much for your answer. I have modify the code but i have the problem that the executeQueryAsync fuction not run. I Have put more alert so i can see that the problem is by the executeQueryAsync. I have put the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems() ,"sp.js"); but the same problem. Do you have any idea for my.

Comment: Based on your code above, the "function onQuerySucceededUpdate"and "function onQueryFailedUpdate" code should not be written in the "createUpdateListItem" method, this may be the reason why the executeQueryAsync fuction is not run , try moving them outside of the "createUpdateListItem" method .

Comment: Hello Zella pleace see my code

Answer (score 0):

```js
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Lista');

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml(
                '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' +
                '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
            );
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
            );
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemInfo = '';
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('ID');
                    //'\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
                   
                for (var i = 0; i < listItemInfo.length; i++){
                if (listItemInfo.split() == 12) {
                    var siteUrl =
                    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1');
                    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                     alert("ist gleich 12");
                  oListItem.set_item('Location', 'blub');
                  oListItem.update(); 
                  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceess, onQueryFailed);               
                  }
              
              }
            alert(listItemInfo.toString());} 
        
}
         function onQuerySucceess() {

             alert('Item updated!');
        }
 
       function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: My problem is taht can't split the listiteminfo . My fist alert listIteminfoi is 11 but the second is 1112. I need to check if it is =11 , =12 etc. Can you help my, pleace?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).